# Every $4$-dimensional central simple algebra is a quaternion algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am looking at the proof of the above theorem in which it starts like this:

Let $x$ be a non zero element of the central simple algebra such that $x \notin k$ and consider the subalgebra generated by $x$. It is easy to see that the minimal polynomial of $x$ is $P(z)= z^2 - t(x)z + n(x)$ and that $P(z) \in k[z]$ is irreducible.

I am not able to understand how this minimal polynomial was obtained. If anybody has some alternate proof, that also would be helpful.

The notes I am referring to can be found [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/noncommutativealgebra.pdf) and the theorem is 5.5 in these notes.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of $t(x)$ and $n(x)$,

$(z-x)(z-\bar x)=z^2-z(x+\bar x) +x\bar x=z^2-t(x)z+n(x)$

$x$ is obviously a root, and if it weren't irreducible, it would factor into linear factors and thus $x\in k$.

---

As pointed out much later now by m.s., there does appear to be a problem in the cited text. $n$ and $t$ are both defined in terms of a basis which has not been assumed to exist.

I originally interpreted this simply as a question about the minimality of a given polynomial, not as a challenge to the existence of the polynomial, and I was fairly certain the user's question was about why $x$ is a root.

Of course, after proving the theorem without this polynomial, one can conclude that this is precisely the polynomial, in terms of that basis's $n$ and $t$.

Comment: What is $\bar x $ ?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh bottom of page 49. The beginning of the section you cited.

Comment: His confusion is justified, see below.

Comment: @m.s I see. At the time I interpreted the question merely as asking why a polynomial was minimal, not "how could you do that without $n$ and $t$".

Answer (score 3):

I understand your confusion, since in the notes you cited, the reduced norm and the reduced trace are defined **by means of** a quaternionic basis, so it is circular to use them the proof of a Theorem that asserts existence of such a basis.

Let $B$ be a four dimensional, central simple algebra over $k$. Then either $B  \cong M_2(k)$, which has a quaternionic basis, or $B$ is a division algebra. So we may assume that $B$ is a division algebra. Now the statement one needs is:

> For any $x \in B$ with $x \notin k$, the sub-algebra $k[x]$ is a
>   quadratic field extension of $k$.

To prove this, we first note that $k[x]$ is a commutative subalgebra of $B$ of finite dimension with no non-zero zero divisors (because $B$ has none). Therefore, $k[x]$ is a field. Since $B$ is not commutative, we have $k[x] \neq B$ and since $x \notin k$, we have $k[x] \neq k$. Hence $[k[x]: k] \in \{2,3\}$. Since $k[x]$ is a simple $k$-algebra, the double centralizer theorem  -- precisely, part b) of Theorem 4.14 in the notes you cited -- implies that $[k[x]: k][Z_{B}(k[x]):k] = 4$, hence $[k[x]: k] = [Z_{B}(k[x]):k] = 2$.

Comment: I guess $\in\{2,3\}$ was intended to be $\in \{2,4\}$?

Comment: No, I wrote 2 and 3, because these are the possible dimensions of a  proper subspace with dimension > 1 of a 4-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I have huge doubts that this was actually the OP's question, but +1 nevertheless for bringing up a critical problem with the text and its solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. I assumed you were using the dimension equation $|B:k|=|B:k[x]||k[x]:k|$, which would rule out $3$ right away.

Comment: Yes, good point. Knowing the dimension of the centralizer is nevertheless relevant, because it implies that k[x] is its own centralizer, which is important in the rest of the proof.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I didn't mean to say that it wasn't important, only that's the assumption that prompted my first comment.