# CSA of dimension 4 are quaternion.

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

I am looking for a proof *not using Wedderburn-Artin nor Skolem-Noether* of:

> Every central simple (division) algebra of dimension 4 over $F$ (a field of characteristic $\neq 2$) is quaternion.

All the proofs that I found use either Wedderburn-Artin and/or Skolem-Noether and I can't figure out an alternative proof.

I found a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543541/every-4-dimensional-central-simple-algebra-is-a-quaternion-algebra), but they also use Skolem-Noether.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question: usually a quaternion algebra is _defined_ to be a CSA of dimension 4.

Comment: My text book defines it explicitely with the generators $i,j (char(F) \neq 2)$, and then proves the equivalence between the two. But it uses Wedderburn-Artin. Now it is solved anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof is also asked in Exercise $15$ on page $136$ in the book Noncommutative Algebra by Benson Farb and R. Keith Dennis [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=sELhBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=Show+that+every+4-dimensional+central+simple+algebra+over+a+field+F+is+isomorphic+to+a+quaternion+algebra&source=bl&ots=NkjUfIfrnG&sig=Mtt67oSs6y3dd11MWuOy0IL1_k8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH6cvx36vUAhXGvRQKHYGjDSc4ChDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=Show%20that%20every%204-dimensional%20central%20simple%20algebra%20over%20a%20field%20F%20is%20isomorphic%20to%20a%20quaternion%20algebra&f=false). The hint is as follows: *See the proof of the Frobenius Theorem*. So you could follow this proof in the book.
On the other hand I do not see why we should avoid Wedderburn, or Skolem-Noether. These are very basic results in this area which one should study.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to make a Proof with the book. I would like the both theorems because they would lead too far away from the goal of what I'm doing right now...